# how to set custom sound on local notification sound property

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am creating an alarm app by displaying local notification.i want to add custom sound to my local notification.i have added a sound @"crow.wav" to my resource folder and to my documents directory and in the notification.soundname property i have my filename like `notification.soundname = @"crow.wav"`.But the problem is when the alarm rings the notification rings with the default sound .it does not ring with the sound that i have provided.What may be the problem.Please help me in solving this problem.Thanks.

Comment: You left out the bit about the sound being longer the 30s.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible for us to set the soundName property as a name of audio file from other than main bundle i.e. if we want to assign the name of audio file from resources is possible .but at the same time if we try the same using file inside document directory apple wont allow you to do so . So please dont try it .U can refer apple docs for referance .try for another way for doing this ..plz .Reply

Information collected from iPhoneDocs:
    1) Please Go through the documents and shaded part in it.

```
    2)Scheduling Local Notifications
```

Configure the substance of the notification: alert, icon badge number, and sound.
    •   The alert has a property for the message (the alertBody property) and for the title of the action button or slider (alertAction); both of these string values can be internationalized for the user’s current language preference.
    •   You set the badge number to display on the application icon through the applicationIconBadgeNumber property.
    •   You can assign the filename of a nonlocalized custom sound in the application’s main bundle to the soundName property; to get the default system sound, OR assign UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName. Sounds should always accompany an alert message or icon badging; they should not be played otherwise.